# Android Studio: Unkown sourse: ViewGroup

Tags: android, kotlin

After updating an old project I'm having issues. When i try to open activity app crashes and I'm getting this error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.Map.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference at CounterpartyAdapter$ViewHolder._$_findCachedViewById(Unknown Source:6)`. At this line a have `ViewGroup` import. I tried to open ViewGroup and all i see its file full of error. When i try to edit it it show me this:

[image: pop up]

Is there any way to fix it? It happened after updating entire project by upping CompileSDKVersion, Gradle and Kotlin version to latest

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?